# Is there a tablet device that supports ARCore

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

Is there a tablet device that supports ARCore?
And if not, when will there be one?

Comment: >At this time there are a [bunch of Android tablets](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) supporting ARCore 1.8 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ARCoreForAll. You could also try installing the arcore apk provided by google onto a tablet to see if it works. I have had a significant amount of luck installing the official arcore apk on non-supported devices. There's no officially supported tablet yet.